# View data from another controller in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app.

I have two controllers 'home' and 'work'. How can I display data from 'work' model in the home/index view?

Unfortunately, I don't know the terminology to better formulate the question, but actually I want to achieve that on the home page I can display the last few works.

The part where I enter/edit data works fine. When I go to the `/Works/Index` page, I see all the entered data. How to display, for example, the last 4 on the home page of the application

In `index.cshtml` I have

```
@model IEnumerable<Website.Models.Work>                
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="gallery-item wow fadeInUp delay-0-2s">
            <img src="~/assets/images/gallery/gallery-1.jpg" alt="Gallery">
                <div class="gallery-content">
                    <span class="category"><a href="portfolio-details.html">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tag)</a></span>
                    <h5><a href="portfolio-details.html">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Headline)</a></h5>
                </div>
       </div>
   </div>
}
```

But I get an error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Hi @Carlo, where do you get the displayed data? Any way, I share two solutions below. One is get displayed data in another controller, The other is get displayed data in correct controller and send it to another controller. More details could be helpful if you share the backend code.

Comment: Thank you @Rena for your answer. But that does not work for me. I don't need to redirect anywhere I only need to show data on front page. My app is actually a website. Website has sections like latest work, news, etc. all that is stored on DB and when I go to localhost/Works I see all of the latest works, when I navigate to localhost/News I see all published news. But my question is how to display some of that data on website front page https://localhost/. I can post code just tell me what do you need?

Comment: Or how to load data from Work model /Views/Home/Index.cshtml

Comment: Hi @Carlo, if you just want to display the model data to page, I update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know how to display the data on page, here is a working demo below:

HomeController

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{

    private readonly YourDbContext _context;        
    public HomeController(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
       //get the last 4 records...
        var model = _context.Work.AsEnumerable().Reverse().Take(4).ToList();
        return View(model);            
    }
}
```

Home/Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Website.Models.Work>                
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="gallery-item wow fadeInUp delay-0-2s">
            <img src="~/assets/images/gallery/gallery-1.jpg" alt="Gallery">
                <div class="gallery-content">
                    <span class="category"><a href="portfolio-details.html">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tag)</a></span>
                    <h5><a href="portfolio-details.html">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Headline)</a></h5>
                </div>
       </div>
   </div>
}
```